# Slight variation of Mertens' third theorem. Do we have an estimate of $\sum_{d \mid n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)}\dfrac{\sigma_0(d)}{d}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Define $f(n)$ to be:

$$
\sum_{d \mid n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)}\dfrac{\sigma_0(d)}{d}
$$

But $\sigma_0(d) = 2^{\omega(d)}$ for any $d \mid n\#$ a primorial, so:

$$
f(n) = \prod_{p \text{ prime} \\ p \leq n} \dfrac{1}{\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{p}\right)}
$$

Mertens' third theorem has as $1$ instead of a $2$ there.

So what would be an asymptotic estimate of $f(n)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\prod\limits_{2<p \le n} {\left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)^{ - 1} } & = \exp \left( { - \sum\limits_{2<p \le n} {\log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)} } \right) \\ & = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{2<p \le n} {\frac{2}{p}}  - \sum\limits_{2<p \le n} {\left[ {\frac{2}{p} + \log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)} \right]} } \right).
\end{align*}
Now by [Mertens' second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems)
$$
\sum\limits_{2<p \le n} {\frac{2}{p}}  = 2\log \log n + 2M -1+ \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right),
$$
where
$$
M = \gamma  + \sum\limits_p {\left[ {\frac{1}{p} + \log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{p}} \right)} \right]} 
$$
is the [Meissel–Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant). Also
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{2<p \le n} {\left[ {\frac{2}{p} + \log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)} \right]} & = \sum\limits_{p>2} {\left[ {\frac{2}{p} + \log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)} \right]}  - \sum\limits_{p > n} {\left[ {\frac{2}{p} + \log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)} \right]} 
\\ & = \sum\limits_{p>2} {\left[ {\frac{2}{p} + \log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)} \right]}  - \sum\limits_{p > n} {\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{p^2 }}} \right)} \\ &
 = \sum\limits_{p>2} {\left[ {\frac{2}{p} + \log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)} \right]}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n\log n}}} \right).
\end{align*}
Taking exponentials and simplifying
$$
\prod\limits_{2<p \le n} {\left( {1 - \frac{2}{p}} \right)^{ - 1} }  = C(\log n)^2 +\mathcal{O}(\log n),
$$
where
$$
C = \frac{{e^{2\gamma } }}{4}\prod\limits_{p > 2} {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{p(p - 2)}}} \right)} = \frac{{e^{2\gamma } }}{4\Pi_2}=1.201303559967362\ldots,
$$
with $\Pi_2$ being the [twin prime constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimesConstant.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I will study this in depth later.  I awarded you the answer because you explained more details.  Coincidentally this is coming up in my own twin prime research, so maybe I'll stumble upon the same results as they did.

Comment: Eric has to correct his answer as it is off by a factor of $2$.

Comment: Can you point me to a list of axioms in brief for working with the asymptotics present here?  I'm in awe of how you showed those steps so fluidly.  I'm no where near your level in analytic number theory, so how does one get there?

Comment: I belive the only non-trivial part is
$$\sum\limits_{p > n} {\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{p^2 }}} \right)}  =\mathcal{O}(1)\frac{\pi(n)}{n^2}+ \mathcal{O}(1)\int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\pi (t)}}{{t^3 }}dt}  =\mathcal{O}(1)\frac{\pi(n)}{n^2}+ \mathcal{O}(1)\int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 \log t}}}  = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n\log n}}} \right),$$ which relies on Abel's summation formula and PNT. The rest is elementary manipulation and application of known results for which I gave references. Please point to the part that needs more clarification.

Comment: You can also use the more elementary inequality $$
\sum\limits_{p > n} {\frac{1}{{p^2 }}}  \le \sum\limits_{k \ge n} {\frac{1}{{k(k + 1)}}}  = \frac{1}{n},
$$ which gives a weaker estimate but is enough for our purposes.

Comment: Let me direct you to where these formulas show up (hence question): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473585/the-twin-prime-pseudo-metric-on-the-integers-is-a-topological-group-formed  If you expand the prime average counter function, and convert floors to modular residues, then $(b-a)$ times question formula above appears as a summation.  But there's another summation involving $(b - x)_{(d)}$ etc which is the problematic one.  If the first summation infinitely often greater than the second summation, then twin primes is true.  Which just means that $d^n(a,b) \gt 0$ i.o in $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Asymptotically,

$$g(n) = \prod_{2 < p < n}^{p \text{ prime}} 1-\frac2p \sim \frac{4C_2e^{-2\gamma}}{(\log n)^2} \approx \frac{0.83244}{(\log n)^2}$$

And presumably your expression is simply the reciprocal of that, i.e.,

$$f(n) \sim \frac{e^{2 \gamma}(\log n)^2}{4C_2} \approx 1.2013(\log n)^2$$

where $C_2$ is the twin prime constant:

$$C_2 = \prod_{p>2}^{p \text{ prime}} \frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2} \approx 0.66016$$

Note: or just look at the other answer, which does a better job and shows the full derivation.

Comment: please define $C_2$

Comment: Oh! Apologies. $C_2$ is the [twin prime constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimesConstant.html). Edited into the main answer just now. Note that this equality can be determined using the usual sum in Mertens's third theorem.

Comment: If you include $p=2$, $g(n)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Gary And even worse, the reciprocal becomes undefined. I'll go edit that...

Comment: You are off by a factor of $2$. It comes from the first term of the sum in $2M$, see my derivation. Also you may write $\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)$ in the defintion of $g(n)$ to make it clear what is included in the product.

Comment: Whoops! Indeed. The $4$ comes from the $2$ term in both Mertens' Theorem and the TP Constant.