# For any $I = [p_{n} + 2, p_{n+1}^2 - 2]$ there exists an affine function in the first quadrant that lower bounds the twin prime average counter on $I$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, twin-primes

#### Motivation

**Lemma.**  $h_n(x) = \sum\limits_{d \mid p_n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)} \sum\limits_{r^2 = 1 \pmod d} \left\lfloor \frac{x - r}{d}\right\rfloor$ counts the number of twin prime averages in the interval $[p_n +2, x]$ for all $p_n + 2 \leq x \leq p_{n+1}^2 - 2$.

**Proof.** I can prove the above using elementary definitions and inequalities.

**Conjecture.**  An affine function lower-bounding $h_n(x)$ is:

$$
f_n(x) = \frac{-n}{2} + x\sum_{d \mid p_n\#}\frac{(-1)^{\omega(d)}{\begin{cases} 2^{\omega(d) -1},2\mid d \\ 2^{\omega(d)}, \text{else} \end{cases}}}{d} 
$$

In other words the slope $m$ of the trend line $f_n$ is precisely the sum of all $(-1)^{\omega(d)} \frac{1}{d}$ such that $r \in$ the group $G_d = \{ r \in \{0, \dots, d-1\} : r^2 = 1\pmod d\}$ which is the same thing as above.

---

#### Evidence

[image: Graph of y-offset b = -n/2 line next to the twin prime counter on that interval]

This code which generates the above screenshot showing the trend line above next to what it lower bounds, but zoomed in on the window of $X = p_{n} + 2... 2\cdot( p_{n+1}^2 - 2)$.

```
from sympy import *

def f(n, x, P):
   S = 0
   R = -(n+1)/2
   Q = 0 
      
   for d in divisors(P):
      T = 0
      U = 0
      V = 0
      for r in range(0, d):
         if (r**2 - 1) % d == 0:
            U += floor((x- r)/d)
            T += (x - r)/d
            V += floor((-r)/d)
      S += (-1)**primeomega(d) * U
      R += (-1)**primeomega(d) * T
      Q += (-1)**primeomega(d) * V
      
   return  R, S, Q

X = Symbol('X')

N =5

M = primorial(N)
S,R, Q = f(N, X, M)

print(S)
print(R)
print(f'Q={Q}')

a = prime(N+1) + 2
b = prime(N + 2)**2 - 2



delta = 1.0
n = int((b-a) / delta)

Xvals = []
Yvals = []
Xvals1 = []
Yvals1 = []

max = 0

for x in range(a, 2*(b+1)):
   Xvals1.append(x)
   z,y,_= f(N, x, M)
   
   if abs(z-y) > max:
      max = abs(z-y)
      
   Yvals1.append(z)
   Yvals.append(y)
   
print(f'Max diff = {max}')
   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot(Xvals1, Yvals1)
plt.plot(Xvals1, Yvals)
plt.show()
```

---

It's already been proven that the slope is indeed correct, [here by Bryan Moehring](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4683353/26327), even for more general sums of such step functions.  In other words, any such trend line or bounding line must have a slope of that form, so that is solved for.  I merely seek a constant for $b$.  I think $b = -n/2$ seems like good choice.  Judging by zooming in on the above $n=5$ screenshot, it's a really tight bound.

---

#### Question

How can I prove that $b = -n/2$ is sufficient so that $f_n(x) = mx + b \leq h_n(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$?  (For sufficiently large $n$)

---

#### Further Motivation

$$
\sum_{d \mid p_n\#}\frac{(-1)^{\omega(d)}{\begin{cases} 2^{\omega(d) -1},2\mid d \\ 2^{\omega(d)}, \text{else} \end{cases}}}{d} = \\
(1-\frac{1}{2})\sum_{d \mid \frac{p_n\#}{2}}\frac{(-2)^{\omega(d)}}{d}
$$

So this seems like something to which we can apply Mertens' Theorems to.

If the estimate for $b$ is correct, that would mean we can expect at least:

$$
f_n(p_{n+1}^2-2) = -\frac{n}{2} + (p_{n+1}^2 -2) M
$$

twin prime averages to occur in the interval $I = [p_{n} + 2, p_{n+1}^2 - 2]$.  Where $M = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{d \mid \frac{p_n\#}{2}}\frac{ (-2)^{\omega(d)}}{d}$.  And $M$ is handled [nicely by Mertens application](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472059/26327).

Comment: Have you heard of a Brun sieve? Halberstam & Richert's _Sieve Methods_ and Iwaniec's _Opera de Cribro_ are two good references for it.

Comment: @TravorLZH That is a good tip.  I see this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun_sieve  They also use an affine function for estimating!  Thanks.